# How to make an excel chart for sales data by year and department?

Tags: microsoft-excel, charts

Assume data like this:

```
Year       Dept       Sales
2015       Digital    150,000
2015       TV         250,000
2015       Print      100,000
2016       Digital    300,000
2016       TV         245,000
2016       Print      110,000
```

I want the y axis to be the sales numbers and the x-axis to be the year and then a line for each department represented on the chart itself. What type of chart do I need for this, I tried some of the defaults and it never comes up right so either I'm picking the wrong type or not organizing my data properly

Comment: Not organizing the data correctly.  Make a separate table for each department.

Answer (score 1):

You can create a Pivot Chart to get your result.

Select the data range and go to Insert- Pivot Chart- Drag fields to correct area in Field List, then you will get the result you want:

[image]